# split navigation overflow - header into footer if browser window width small

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, overflow

[image]

Here is the actual HTML and CSS without the desired overflow in the footer

- http://jsfiddle.net/KristjanLaane/cHmkj/10/
- ( resize the result window to one with smaller width to see the issue )

#### And should work with iframes

Unlike what you see in the fiddle, I'm actually using iframes so as to reuse the navigation elements in many web-pages:

```
<body>
<iframe class="header" src="header.html">
</iframe>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="holder">
      <div class="content">
      </div>
    </div>
    <iframe class="footer" src="footer.html">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can't move content with [CSS] if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Connor thanks, a js solution should work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify css rules for different screen sizes with @media. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/drhe8/1/ . (I placed the links both in header and footer and used rules to hide/display them depending on screen size. It's quick and dirty but i bet you'll get the idea.

```
@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .footer {
      display:block;
  }
  .header {
      display:none;
  } 
}
```